# How to use secondary-content with link_to helper in rails with materialize css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, materialize

Hi everyone i wish to add/span an icon inside a `link_to` block using the materialized `collection secondary-content class` link in [this example](https://github.com/foliwe/search/blob/master/app/assets/images/Selection_017.png).

#### This is my code

```
<div class="collection">
<%=link_to "Name",resource_name_path, class: "collection-item  #{active? resource_name_path}" %> 
</div>
```

#### Here is the HTML example on the website

```
<li class="collection-item"><div>Alvin<a href="#!" class="secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">send</i></a></div></li>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the anchor name in `link_to` and pass a block to do multiline stuff! :) Here's how:

```
<%= link_to resource_name_path, class: "collection-item  #{active? resource_name_path}" do %>
  <i class="material-icons">Name/Alvin?</i>
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps :)